# Why is the 'classical' Nimzo-Indian called the Noa variation?

Tags: opening, terminology, nimzo-indian

I recently played 1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Bb4 4. Qc2 d5, and it was coded as the **Noa** variation of the Nimzo-Indian. There was a Josef Noa of Hungary, who lived from, 1856-1903, but his recorded games do not include a Nimzo-Indian, let alone this variation. Why is it named after him then?

Comment: @HerbWolfe The OP wrote "his recorded games do not include a N-I." Do you seriously believe that by "N-I" he meant "Noa"? I don't see why anyone would abbreviate "Noa" at all, much less abbreviate it to "N-I".

Comment: @bof a simple check of his recorded games does show that he played at least one Nimzo, and it was not a Noa.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Completely irrelevant. We do not edit other people's posts to correct their facts. You can do that in a comment or an answer, not by putting your words in the OP's mouth.

Answer (score 7):

The Oxford Companion to Chess says that the Noa Variation of the Nimzo-Indian was played regularly by Josef Noa, but that he reached the position after 1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Bb4 4.Qc2 Nf6.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because he has notable games playing with it or he had analysis published on it.